C++ Enum with External Linkage Not Causing Linkage Conflict
I'm learning about external linkage in C++ and came across a point in cppreference stating that enum has external linkage. However, I encountered an issue where no linkage conflict occurs when defining the same enum class in different files within the same namespace.
Here are my code snippets:
test1.cpp:
#include <iostream>

namespace A {
    enum TestEnum{Apple};
}

int main(){
    std::cout << A::TestEnum::Apple << std::endl;
}

test2.cpp:
namespace A {
    enum TestEnum{Apple};
}

g++ test1.cpp test2.cpp -o test

I expected the compiler to raise a multiple definition error, but it compiles without any issues. Could someone explain why there's no conflict despite the enums having external linkage? What am I missing about the linkage of enum types in this context?
Thank you in advance for your help!
Additional
I am just puzzled by the following content on cppreference:

Any of the following names declared at namespace scope have external linkage, unless they are declared in an unnamed namespace or their declarations are attached to a named module and are not exported (since C++20):
enumerations;

It indicates that enumerations have external linkage.

This code does not compile: error: 'cout' is not a member of 'std'. The link stage can't be reached.

It looks like you assume that TestEnum::A is like a global variable that needs to be linked. Even if it was, defining global variable twice would be an ODR violation.

Your code is the same as if TestEnum was defined in a header included by both cpps (because both definitions are identical), which is a trivial and commonly used pattern. And they were not identical it's an ODR violation.
